# Execute Mongo commands by php script

Tags: php, mongodb, shell

I tried to use `$shell = shell_exec('mongod');` to start mongodb it displays `NULL`. But when i execute `$shell = shell_exec('dir');` through php script it works.

I was wondering is their a way to execute `Mongodb Commands` through PHP Script.

I have looked all over internet but did not found any query related to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To start a service require `sudo` permission, can you run your PHP scripts with sudo and see what happen?

Comment: @Ramratan Gupta sudo commands are for Linux on I use Windows will it work

Comment: What sort of MongoDB commands are you trying to run? Do you actually want to start a `mongod` server from your PHP application, or are you trying to send commands to a MongoDB deployment? Instead of using `shell_exec`, I expect you are looking for the [MongoDB PHP library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/).

Comment: in windows `sudo` is run as administrator see here in detail : https://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/